# WPF - Binding Data To DataGrid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a problem in binding some data to a data grid.

```
  <DataGrid IemSource={Binding SomeData}>
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>

            </DataGridTemplateColumn>

            <DataGridTemplateColumn>
               <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                 <DataTemplate>
                    <ItemsControl ItemSource={Binding SomeOtherDataSource}>
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                        <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
                         <ComboBox/>
                     </StackPanel>
                    </ItemsControl>
                 </DataTemplate>
             </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
               <DataTemplate>
                    <ComboBox  />
              </DataTemplate>
          </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn>


        </DataGrid.Columns>

 </DataGrid>
```

The problem is that the data source **SomeData** is totally different from the data source **SomeOtherDataSource**. For example, if what SomeData is a list of objects from Class A, then SomeOtherDataSource is a list of objects from class B. There is no connection at all between those 2 classes. They are totally different. So, consequently, bindings for first two columns work. But the binding for last column ( 3rd column) does not work.

Can someone help ?

Comment: What does the 3rd column have to do with the individual rows? How do they correlate?

Comment: 3 columns ? the first column contains FirstName, the second column contains LastName. The third column contains some numbers. It comes from a different data source

Comment: Like in an excel worksheet where the 3rd column is _totally_ unrelated to the first 2 columns? So the first name and last name have nothing to do with what is shown in the 3rd column?

Comment: yes....you are right

Comment: So if I understand properly, `SomeData` and `SomeOtherDataSource` are 2 propeties you have in code behind or in view model (MVVM case) ?

Comment: I can't think of anything without coding in Viewmodells bringing the columns in relation to the rows to support that. But if they are not related thats a bit difficult too.