# WPF - Binding a list of a string to a column in Data Grid

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I have a datagrid with three columns.

```
 <DataGrid IemSource={Binding SomeData}>
       <DataGrid.Columns>
           <DataGridTemplateColumn>

           </DataGridTemplateColumn>

          <DataGridTemplateColumn>

          </DataGridTemplateColumn>

          <DataGridTemplateColumn>
             <DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                   <ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeList}">
                     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                       <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
                       <ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding }"/>
                    </StackPanel>
                  </ItemsControl>
               </DataTemplate>
            </DataGridTemplateColumn.HeaderTemplate>
         <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
             <DataTemplate>
                 <ComboBox  />
            </DataTemplate>
       </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn>


    </DataGrid.Columns>
```

SomeData is a object collection of ClassA. Class A contains two string fields and I have binded them to the first 2 columns.

The class contains a List of string variables of which the name is SomeList. I have binded it to the 3rd column. I need to attach it to the combobox in the header of column 3. But this code does not give me what I want.

can someone help ?

Comment: Same question posted 1h ago... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117818/wpf-binding-data-to-datagrid

Comment: you'll find that there is a difference. I have changed the structure of the list

Comment: you can check this : http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/21975.adding-combobox-in-wpf-datagrid-header-using-mvvm-pattern.aspx

Comment: @nidarshanifernando Then you should have edited your post

Answer (score 0):

Your problem seems to be that you add the StackPanel as item to the ItemsControl instead of using it in a DataTemplate.

Instead of

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
        <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
        <ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding }"/>
    </StackPanel>
</ItemsControl>
```

it should look like this:

```
<ItemsControl ItemSource="{Binding SomeList}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="SomeTopic"/>
                <ComboBox ItemSource="{Binding }"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```

Comment: It hides the combobox itself. If I do like that, it does not even show the combobox